# Guess the number – creating number range JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, range, operation

I am currently trying to create a Guess the Number game using Javascript. I have set the code to display  a different output depending on the number entered.

However, I would like to add range to this. For example, if the guess is within 10, above or below, the output should read "Almost". However, if the user is out of this range, it should read something different.

What operation should I use? Currently I'm just using:

```
    if(userGuess < randomNumber) {
            lowOrHi.textContent = 'Your guess is out by 10 – please guess again!';
```

But this doesn't reflect the range as I'd like it to.

Comment: You can have multiple comparisons in one if statement. `x < 2 || x > 3` will match if a number entered is outside the range 2-3. The `||` means "or".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use absolute value to get the distance between the `userGuess` and the `randomNumber`

you can get it with [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)

```js
const randomNumber = 4 // chosen by fair dice roll.
                       // guaranteed to be random.
                   
let userGuesses = [42, -15, 2]

for (let guess of userGuesses) {
  if (Math.abs(guess - randomNumber) <= 5) {
    // the guess is in the range [random - 5; random + 5]
    console.log(`guess ${guess} is very close`)
  } else if (Math.abs(guess - randomNumber) <= 20) {
    // the guess is in the range [random - 20; random + 20]
    console.log(`guess ${guess} is not that far`)
  } else {
    console.log(`guess ${guess} is pretty far`)
  }
}
```

as you can see it works if you're under the wanted number or over it

Comment: Ah, I see you're implementing [this random number algorithm](https://xkcd.com/221/) :P

Comment: Yea, Smart programmer confirmed! +1

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the difference between guessed number and random number is within range of 10.

```
var difference = Math.abs(userGuess - randomNumber);
if(difference > 10) {
    lowOrHi.textContent = 'Your guess is out by 10 – please guess again!';
} else {
    lowOrHi.textContent = 'Your guess is almost correct!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
if((userGuess-randomNumber)<-10||(userGuess-randomNumber)>10) {
    console.log('Your guess is out by 10 – please guess again!');}
else {
    console.log("Almost");
}
```